# SQL query to Sequelize query

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

```
select *
From Visitors
join CsvData on
CsvData.fileName = Visitors.fileName
```

How to make join like above.

```
db.Visitors.find({
    include:[{
        model: CsvData,
        joinCondition: {
            Visitors.fileName : CsvData.fileName  //*wrong syntax but rough idea
        }
    }]
})
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there :) You first want to [associate](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/associations/) the two models. Assuming `fileName` is defined as a primary key on `CsvData`:

```
Visitors.hasMany(CsvData, {
  as: 'CsvDataItems',
  foreignKey: 'fileName'
});

Visitors.findAll({
  include:[{
    model: CsvData,
    as: 'CsvDataItems' // Must match the "as" specified in the association above
  }]
}).then(function(results) {
  console.log('Success!', results);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.error('Something went wrong', err);
});
```

Note that if you wanted a right join (I know you didn't ask, but hey) you can add `required: true` to the `include` object.